# What is the best IDE for actionscript3 development

Tags: actionscript-3, ide

I am currently using FlashDevelop for my Actionscript3 development.  I have also tried my hand with using Flex3 for my Actionscript3 development.  I was curious if FDT was superior to the former and that if it's cost out-weighs it's usefulness.  Are there any other applications out there to help streamline the process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah by far the best IDE is eclipse with either fdt or flex builder installed (flex builder is just a packaged version of eclipse).  The biggest problem with FlashDevelop is it's lack of debugging tools.  If you get into eclipse, and teach yourself how to properly debug an application it can save you SOOO much time.

As for flex builder or fdt that's entirely up to you. The one big benefit fdt has is that it still supports AS2 development.  FDT also has a lot of other nice features like code templating.

I have both but i mainly stick to flex builder for my flash work as for me i like the way i can use it for both flash and flex work and can easily switch between the two with minimum effort.  If i had to do work in as2 again (god forbid) i'd definitely wouldn't heistate to switch back into the fdt environment.

Comment: My biggest problem with Flex Builder is that its expensive, and I'm cheap. FlashDevelop is free, small, and efficient, in my opinion (grant you, lacking debugging). I was not aware of FDT, now I am: did you know that it has a free Open Source Development licence?

Comment: Agreed about the cost but but luckily the company i work for is pretty good with software licenses.  No i didn't know about the open source license. sounds interesting...

Comment: As a developer used to a development environment like Visual Studio, I can say that the Eclipse Plugin is the only Flex IDE that I would deem acceptable. However, I do not consider a debugger to be an optional feature, so your results may vary.

Comment: FlashDevelop has experimental debugging support as of version 3.1.

Comment: Those willing to try out FDT, Powerflasher announced the Open Beta programme yesterday as part of releasing FDT 4 Release Candidate: http://tekkie.flashbit.net/flash/get-a-taste-of-professional-flash-development-with-fdt-4-trial

Free FDT 4 licence will be good until October 17th 2010.

Comment: IntelliJ is so much better than any eclipse based IDE. in every way really. picked it up an couple of years ago and haven't used anything else since

Answer (score 6):

FlashDevelop is a very good IDE for AS3 development. Haven't tried FDT, but tried Flexbuilder. I can say that it's much better for pure AS3 development (no mxml stuff). 
and it's free.

Answer (score 3):

I have to expand euge1979's answer.

The [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/flexdownloads/index.html) (including framework, compiler, etc) is forked into a free Adobe owned Version and an open source version. Either way, you can compile SWFs for free.

The [Flex Builder](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3email) is NOT free. You have a 30 days trial.

A good thing to note is that FDT in the next version (from 3.1 to 3.2) will be able to handle mxml, thus making it equal to Flex Builder in terms of features. I really love some of the FDT features that makes common tasks easy - like formatting or creating functions, objects & etc.

Right now - stick with Flex Builder.

PS: Flex Builder is built upon Eclipse but it messes it all up. I experienced a lot of problems with FB as plugin and if I installed plugins into FB. And all the power vanished if I can't use it as plugin or install others into the eclipse.

My favorite environment right now is: [Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/) + FDT + PyDev + PHPDev

Comment: Just an FYI, the Flex Builder trial, at least as of the time I write this, is 60 days.

Comment: You CAN install plugins in Flash Builder, you just need to enable them by editing a configuration file:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023044/getting-the-message-cannot-start-the-update-ui-when-trying-to-run-the-update

Answer (score 3):

flex builder because

1. you can debug
2. you can use the profiler you can real dig in to the player memory 
   fix memory leak
3. eclipse can do so much for you with tone of plug ins

- mylyn connect your data base bugs to your IDE and much more link svn commit to a task 

 - subeclipse plugin for SVN

Answer (score 1):

Just started looking into the AS3-only programming, always looking for opensource tools, so flashdevelop were the first choice.

Not having any breakpoint features is not viable when developing applications. Even though its a upcoming feature I am sticking with flexbuilder until its implemented in flasdevelop.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use FDT for a lot of FLASH coding (not Flex) but I find Flex builder to be on par.  The main thing i feel FlexBuilder needs is good refactoring.  Moving from a java project to flex, and then wanting to refactor things is a pain. There is some, but it just needs to be on the same level as Java in eclipse.

From memory, FDT may have had better refactoring support.

Flex builder also has better style sheet support etc.  I don't know if one is better, they are a bit different.  In truth I find flex builder to be good enough (and if the next version just makes a few improvements) that I don't miss FDT.

If you do any AS2, FDT is great.  It even gives proper compile time errors (versus flash ide).  I am a few builds old now for FDT (i have 3.1, but not latest).  Actually FDT's error checking and general AS2/3 parser is BETTER.

Answer (score 1):

I'm mainly using FDT for the same reasons as above + I'm not on Windows.

I just wanted to add that the FlashDevelop is a very generous contribution to the flash open source community (a big thanks to Philippe and Mika) featuring a long list of nice tools.

Actually I'm still missing the "intelligent auto-completition" tool which is far better than FDT/FB, Haxe is supported, you can browse swf content from the project explorer, project templates are easily created, and so on...

Another point to consider is that FlashDevelop is literally 100 times lighter than FDT (3.7M against 297M).

You should give the FDTs or FBs 30-days-trial a go. But if you're happy with FlashDevelop it can be worth saving the money (IMO, FDT is overpriced) and support open source.

The FD team is currently working on the debugger and profiling tools so with some help it will get there ;)

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to personal taste, but I actually prefer FlashDevelop to FDT and FB. And being free doesn't hurt!

Answer (score 1):

[Jetbrains IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) coupled with something else (FlexBuilder or FlashDevelop)

It's refactoring tools alone are indespensible. Syntax improvements over FlexBuilder.

Cons: 
it is a slower IDE (9.02) but I'll gladly put up with that for all the added functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Flash Develop or FDT, although I hear FDT runs much slower than Flex Builder. I used to be a Flash Programmer and I used the Flash IDE..I switched to Flex Builder and I love it.

Comment: I heard the opposite: http://twitter.com/alecmce/status/7693754617

Answer (score 0):

FYI for anyone not aware: Flex Builder can be had for free if you're a student or teacher. And I am pretty sure there is no longer a 'can't be used for commercial application' restriction.

Comment: They also recently started giving free licenses to the unemployed. https://freeriatools.adobe.com/

Comment: @quoo. 60 days trial to be exact.

Comment: Not sure if it's changed, but when I posted this, it was not a 60 day trial it was a full free license.

Answer (score 0):

There's also **AXDT open-source alternative** to FDT/Flash Builder. It's not as good, but it delivers nicely esp. for those just starting on Flash Platform and not willing to spend considerably on developer tools.

See [AXDT: open-source cross-platform alternative for Flash development](http://tekkie.flashbit.net/flash/axdt-open-source-cross-platform-alternative-for-flash-development) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer the normal Flash IDE (currently CS5).  I work very closely with the art work provided for my projects though.

I use SVN to back my work.
In my experience with Flex Builder (now Flash Builder) or perhaps Eclipse as a whole.  There are many temporary files made, some times to the point that it was confusing which folder to look in...  and SVN was often obstructed by this automated pile of files.

also Flex Builder projects for teams, didn't seem to keep their settings across SVN, for all users.

either way i like Flash because its a little simpler, but i usually work on smaller projects that don't need the fancy stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In comparison to Flash Develop, Flex builder which is now called Flash Builder, is the best IDE because it comes with more powerful features:

1)  Debugging is easy.
2)  Supporting iOS,android, and blackberry application creation.
3)  Our application connect with xml,dataset and api's.
4)  Syntax generation Improved.
4)  Drag and Drop components on stage and code is generated at the same time for that   component in mxml file.
5)  Its also support PHP coding and also a new framework launched separately for PHP.
6) Remoting can be done as AS3 remoting in flash.