# Getting the message "Cannot start the update ui..." when trying to run the update UI in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to run the update manager in Eclipse, I get the error "Cannot launch the Update UI. This installation has not been configured properly for Software Updates."

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try running eclipse with the -clean tag when you start the executable.  It may or may not sort out the silly issues Eclipse seems to throw up from time to time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are some bugs already entered about that message:

- [bug 238910](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=238910): if your eclipse error log contains:

  !MESSAGE Error parsing profile
  /opt/eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/SDKProfile.profile/1214752385704.profile.

> the .profile was corrupted.
>   I simply deleted the corrupted .profile, restarted eclipse and everything seems
>   to be fine now

- [bug 224658](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=224658) : when self-hosting, p2 update ui won't come up (self-hosting case (that is, Eclipse debugging another instance of Eclipse, as in a plugin development situation)
  Fixed in 3.4
- [bug 230245](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=230245): Failure to read unicode (in certain xml files): Fixed in 3.4

What version of eclipse are you running?

Comment: Version 3.4.1 - I had the first problem, deleting my profile took care of it.

Comment: I too have the same problem while installing new software,But where is that .profile file?

Comment: @Goutam you can see a full path of a `.profile` file in the answer. In your case, the eclipse error log should also include such a full path.

Comment: But that does not exist my profileRegistry is empty

Comment: @Goutam did you check your own eclipse log?

Comment: Yep but that says something like `eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_75
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk
Warning
Mon May 11 14:27:14 IST 2015
Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set correctly in this application's config.ini file.`

Comment: @Goutam OK. You could ask that as a separate question (with a link back to this 5+ years-old answer for context)

Comment: Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163571/eclispse-install-software-says-can-not-complete-the-request

Answer (score 4):

Try enabling *Classic Update*

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Capabilities -> Classic Update
```

If that entry isn't available to you:

1. Shutdown eclipse
2. Navigate to this file

`[yourWORKSPACE]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs`

and try adding this line and restarting eclipse

```
UIActivities.org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.classicUpdate=true
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks.  I didn't find the settings file anywhere before.

Comment: I didnt have the entry and manually added the UIActivities.org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.classicUpdate=true line to [yourWORKSPACE]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs file.

After that we have the option to revert Eclipse to its previous state by clicking Help -> Software Updates -> Manage Configurations -> Revert to Previous, and choose the configuration that was stable and free from the feature that broke eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Flash Builder 4, updated your installation trough auto update and run into this issue, then change this file:

```
Adobe Flash Builder Beta\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.update.ui\dialog_settings.xml
```

and edit the contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section name="Workbench">
    <section name="ModeSelectionPage">
        <item key="new-features-mode" value="false"/>
    </section>
</section>
```

write FALSE instead of TRUE

after restart I have in my help menu two items:

- software updates - classic drop down menu
- software updates - item just under it which gives me the error

But I finally can enter the update dialog and manage updates.

Comment: +1 Thanks Redliner. Using Flash Builder Beta 2, found this file in: [Workspace]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.update.ui/dialog_settings.xml, and now it's working. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try check "Support software instalation in launched application" field in Run Configurations -> Configuration tab.