# Problem updating Eclipse Ganymede

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I am predominately a .NET developer so forgive me if I am missing something obvious.  I use Eclipse Ganymede (3.4.0) for Blackberry development.

I have Blackberry JDE Plugin 4.3.0.8 installed and would like to install 4.5.0.  I try using Help -> Software Updates to get it but get the following error:

***"Cannot launch the Update UI.  This installation has not been configured properly for Software Updates".***

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Failing that any ideas how to install 4.5.0 without using the Update facility in eclipse?  I have installed the 4.5.0 component back but it has not put it into eclipse, just installed files in c:\Program Files\Research In Motion.

I'd rather not do a fresh installation of eclipse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the links guys but I ended up downloading a fresh copy from the website, the archive that I had must have been corrupt somehow because I tried using it again and had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea that comes to mind is that Eclipse doesn't know where to look for updates.

Go to Help->Install New Software (not update)

Click on Available Software Sites

There you can Add, Enable/Disable software sites(repositories)

Comment: How would you specify where it is to look?  I don't get anything up except an error message!

Comment: I don't have an option for "Install New Software" in About dialog, only have "Feature Details", "Plug-in Details" or "Configuration Details".

Comment: Fixed instructions, but they are for 3.5, for 3.4 the process might be slightly different

Answer (score 0):

Download them manually here: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaeclipseplug.jsp

Comment: I've downloaded the "Eclipse Software Update for the BlackBerry JDE v4.5 Component Pack" from here but it's just a zip file.  Where do i put this?  Sorry, as i said i'm not well versed in eclipse development.

Comment: The zip should have the same directory structure as your eclipse directory (especially the /features and /plugins folders). Just copy them in your eclipse installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Jamie said, download Component pack from Blackberry site, and install them with Help->Software Updates->Available Software->Add Site->Archive

**UPDATE** And talking about the error, see
[Getting the message “Cannot start the update ui…” when trying to run the update UI in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023044/getting-the-message-cannot-start-the-update-ui-when-trying-to-run-the-update)

Comment: I get the "Cannot launch the Update UI. This installation has not been configured properly for Software Updates". error when i try to open Software Updates.