# Cannot Install New Software in Eclipse Juno Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am new to Eclipse and I am trying to install the Android ADT plugin for it. When I go to help > install new software, I get the error box "Cannot complete request. This installation has not been configured properly for Software Updates. See error log for details"

Error log:

```
Could not locate the running profile instance. The eclipse.p2.data.area and eclipse.p2.profile properties may not be set correctly in this application's config.ini file.
```

Does anyone know what this means? What do I need to do to install the Android ADT plugin?

Comment: This answer helps me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023044/getting-the-message-cannot-start-the-update-ui-when-trying-to-run-the-updat . Just delete .profile if it's corrupted

Answer (score -1):

FIXED: I uninstalled Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and installed Eclipse Classic. Problem solved!