# Best toolchain for flash (ActionScript 3) game development wanted?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm new to flash and web development too. But I have some background in c#/c++/Qt/python. So, I want to know, what is the best toolchain for quickest dive into.

My task is to write a game for facebook.com/vkontakte.ru. I already have the design doc, great artist and game-designer, so, the coding is the only stumbling block we met. There are no significant obstacles at server-side, but, since we have not much time, I decided to ask some help on suitable toolchain definition.

I think, that web-services (maybe WCF) are perfect for the backend, so, some of them should transfer JSON-ed data from/to client, incapsulate game-logic, and... here is the place I stuck. What next, what should I learn, what tools/toolsets will provide learing/productivity curve that meat least action principle.

Maybe I'm on the wrong way and missing some basic and obvious (for web-devs) things... I do not know, so, any advices will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of tools there's a variety of IDEs available such as:

- [FDT](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/)
- [Flash Develop](http://flashdevelop.org/)
- [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/) (formerly Flex Builder)

Frameworks you might like to get started on:

- [Flixel](http://flixel.org/)
- [Push Button Engine](https://github.com/PushButtonLabs/PushButtonEngine)

Services you might want to look at:

- [GamerSafe](http://gamersafe.com/) (mtx)
- [Mochi Media](http://mochimedia.com/) (ads, social, mtx)
- [Player IO](http://playerio.com/) (multiplayer + highly scalable user databases and file storage)
- [Playtomic](http://playtomic.com/) (analytics mostly ... disclaimer: it's mine)

I have personally produced about 20 games now in Flash and also come from a .NET background (although I was using Flash first, just .NET most).  I mostly use:

- [Adobe Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks/)
- [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/) (this is the least-programmer like IDE but the most visually creative one, it's difficult to wean yourself off of after a decade of the alternatives not existing)
- [Adobe Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashbuilder/) for the CPU/memory profiling is an invaluable component
- [Kindisoft SecureSWF](http://www.kindisoft.com/secureSWF/download.php), I don't use this very much but depending on the nature of your game you might want to encrpyt/obfuscate your code since SWF files are very easy decoded / reconstructed into FLAs

Answer (score 2):

Do these existing questions help you?

- [What is the best IDE for actionscript3 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559044/what-is-the-best-ide-for-actionscript3-development)
- [What are some good Flash game frameworks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284160/what-are-some-good-flash-game-frameworks)

**Edit:**
You might be asking about the Flex SDK.  That is what the three main IDEs use.

- http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex4sdk

The closest thing to an alternative that I'm aware of is [Haxe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/haXe).

Comment: Those both are helpful, but I wanted to get the whole toolchain, what tools do mature flash developers use, not only an IDE and frameworks. Maybe even .NET WCF approach is silly cause write/debug/test/deploy cycle in flash is somewhat brilliant when using the MYSTERYTOOLS (IDE+Server+Framework*N+...) that every flasher knows :) So, I'd vote your answer up, and mark it accepted in some time.

Comment: Flash and webdev are kinda terra incognita for me, so I feel a bit uncomfortable with them :)